# Restrict only some plugins to specific sites in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am looking for a way to set up Google Chrome so that it will run a certain plug-in (Java, what else?) only on whitelisted sites, but other plug-ins (like the PDF viewer) everywhere.

From playing with the policies available for Chrome, I think there are basically two levels of plug-in management:

- List of disabled plugins/enabled plugins: Controls whether a plug-in exists for the browser at all

  This pair of policies applies to plug-ins, but not to sites.
- Default plug-in settings/Allow plug-ins on sites: Controls on which sites plug-ins can run

  This set of policies applies to sites, but not to individual plugins, and it cannot override the first pair.

There appears to be no way to configure Chrome so that some plug-ins only run on whitelisted sites, but others run everywhere by default.

I have also looked at filtering content on the firewall/proxy level, but I'm not convinced it can be done securely there. Filtering by URLs (file names) or content types can be circumvented trivially, and identification by content inspection cannot be safe either.

Comment: You're asking for a level of control that Chrome is not designed to provide.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Chrome add-on [Extension Automation](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghopjgdkodchjclkkfdekhjfomdbakkb) lets you decide on which websites you want an extension to work on, and on which it should be disabled.

> Extension Automation makes it easier to manage other extensions by automatically enabling
>   or disabling them based on the webpages you visit. This extension helps reduce the visual
>   clutter of other extensions and keeps them from running unnecessarily in the background.

Or you can use this [Automatically Enable Incognito Mode For Specific Websites](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/06/automatically-enable-incognito-mode-for-specific-websites-in-google-chrome/) method.

Comment: Perfect in principle, but, alas, it only controls extensions, not plugins.

Comment: The provided link for Extension Automation no longer works, and searching on the Chrome Web Store doesn't return any results for it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ScriptNo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiigbmnaadbkfbmpbfijlflahbdbdgdf?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon). It's very much like a port of the famous Firefox Add-on [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/).

Basically, by default it blocks all scripts and `<OBJECT>`, `<EMBED>`, etc. unless you explicitly allow it.

See also:

- [ScriptNo FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/scriptno/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)
- [Tech Republic interview with the developer](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/security/scriptno-a-preemptive-strike-against-script-attacks-for-chrome/7962)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but ScriptNo's also an all-or-nothing thing.

Answer (score 0):

[Issue 155743](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=155743&q=java%20whitelist&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary) on the Chromium tracker is open for this. Star it if it matches your needs.

I'll try to come back and update this post if the feature gets implemented (but if you notice I haven't, comment below)

Answer (score 0):

**2021: Chrome Version 90**

Click on the Extensions button on the right side of address bar -> Manage Extensions
OR
Open menu by clicking 3 vertical dots at top right corner -> More Tools -> Extensions

Click on Details button of the required Extension and select *On Specific Sites* option under *Site Access*

This allows to Add required sites on which selected Extension remains active.